# Vagrant/Puppet/MySQL localhost issue

Tags: mysql, vagrant, puppet

I have a vagrant file using puppet to configure mysql.

Here is the relevant code in default.pp:

```
class { '::mysql::server':
  override_options => { 'mysqld' => { 'bind_address' => '0.0.0.0' } },


  grants => {
    'root@10.0.2.2/*.*' => {
      ensure     => 'present',
      options    => ['GRANT'],
      privileges => ['ALL'],
      table      => '*.*',
      user       => 'root@10.0.2.2',
    },
  },
}
```

This works, but from the host machine (not the VM) I can only access mysql via 127.0.0.1 and I want to be able to access via localhost (the default for the mysql client).

So my questions are:
1) what is the significance of 10.0.2.2?  ( copied and pasted this from an example)
2) how do I configure the mysql install on the VM to be accessible from the host OS (mac) as

`mysql -u root -h localhost`

I should also note that I tried changing root@10.0.2.2 to root@localhost and this did not work.

thanks!
phil

Answer (score 0):

1. 10.0.2.2 is probably the virtual IP address of the guest OS instance using VirtualBox 'HostOnly' networking.

You should be able to connect to the mysql server in the guest instance using

```
mysql -u root -h 10.0.2.2
```

2. "localhost" has a special meaning with MySQL, it causes clients to try to connect via Unix Domain Sockets instead of TCP. So it tries to connect using a socket file, usually either `/tmp/mysql.sock` or `/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock`, and these are special files only accessible locally to processes on the same operating system instance.

Your VM is a different OS instance though, and so your `mysql` client on the host OS can't access domain socket files on the guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

10.0.2.2 means for which remote IP you grant access to user, by studying vagrant puphpet template 
vagrant/puphpet/puphpet/nodes/Mysql.pp you can see
template definition manifesto, ruby code:

```
  each( $grants ) |$key, $grant| {
    # if no host passed with username, default to localhost
    if '@' in $grant['user'] {
      $user = $grant['user']
    } else {
      $user = "${grant['user']}@localhost"
    }
```

therefore user must by yaml puphpet configured like

```
grants:
     mysql:
         user: dbuser@%
```